# US citizen visiting EU spouse living in Germany (stay > 3 months)

Tags: germany, resident-permit, eu-spouses

I am a US citizen living in the US. My spouse, who is a French (so EU) citizen, is currently living and working in Heidelberg, Germany.

I am currently visiting him in Germany, I plan to return to the US in a couple months, but the duration of my stay here will exceed 3 months.

It is unclear to us whether I have to actively do something like apply for a residence permit ([here](https://www.bamf.de/EN/Themen/MigrationAufenthalt/ZuwandererDrittstaaten/Familie/NachzugZuEUBuergern/nachzug-zu-eu-buergern-node.html), for instance, it sounds like I don't need to do anything). I only did the Heidelberg city registration (anmeldung) at the Bürgeramt when I arrived, also, my spouse registered me on his German health insurance (TK).

Can I get in trouble if I don't apply for a residence permit? Like, when I fly out in a couple months, will a German officer at the airport tell me I exceeded my stay, and what would be the consequences?

Comment: You do not need a **residence permit**, but must apply for a **residence card** as a family member of an EU Citizen. This site states that this will be done automatically after registration. [heidelberg.de - Lebenslagen Einreise und Aufenthaltstitel](https://www.heidelberg.de/hd/-/Lebenslagen/einreise-und-aufenthaltstitel/leb5000405). If not, you should get some confirmation before leaving.

Comment: Whatever the consequences, they should be fairly minor.

Comment: @MarkJohnson that ought to be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a **residence permit**, but must apply for a **residence card** as a family member of an EU Citizen. In some states this must be applied for separately, but for Baden-Württemberg it seems to be done automatically.

The [Heidelberg city site](https://www.heidelberg.de/hd/-/Lebenslagen/einreise-und-aufenthaltstitel/leb5000405) states that this will be done automatically after registration.

> Die Meldebehörde erhebt bei Ihnen die erforderlichen Daten über das Freizügigkeitsrecht und **leitet diese an die Ausländerbehörde weiter**.
> Personen, die Familienangehörige von Unionsbürgerinnen und Unionsbürgern im Sinne des Freizügigkeitsgesetzes/EU sind (zum Beispiel Ehegatten, Lebenspartner und Kinder, die noch nicht 21 Jahre alt sind), **erhalten automatisch eine Aufenthaltskarte**.
>
> > The registration authority collects the necessary data from you about the right of free movement and **forwards it to the immigration authority**.
> > People who are family members of Union citizens within the meaning of the Freedom of Movement Act / EU (e.g. spouses, life partners and children who are not yet 21 years old) **automatically receive a residence card**.

If not, you should get some confirmation before leaving that you have been registered but have not yet received the **residence card**.

---

**Source**:

- [heidelberg.de - Lebenslagen Einreise und Aufenthaltstitel](https://www.heidelberg.de/hd/-/Lebenslagen/einreise-und-aufenthaltstitel/leb5000405)